# Javascript : How to use function in values

Tags: javascript

**Hi**

is it possible to run a function inside a value ?

Comment: `the alert command should be inside the quotes` Why?

Comment: What’s the purpose of the random colons and semicolons at the beginning?

Comment: Booleans are values too. How does "running a function inside a Boolean" look like? O_o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you mean inside a string value, not by itself.

as a function value, yeah

```
var something = (function() {alert("hi"); return "done"})()
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible and the question is not clear. However you can use the `.value` keyword for modifying values for placeholders inside a function.